# references for Jordan Canonical Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am trying to study Jordan forms from the book by Hoffman and Kunze (chapters 6 and 7) and find it a little too terse. Could someone please suggest an alternative reference or a supplement to this book.

Thanks.

Comment: Friedberg, Insel, and Spence have two sections on Jordan Canonical Forms in Chapter 7 of their book.

Answer (score 5):

A very focused and short complete reference is **Weintraub's** [*"Jordan Canonical Form, Theory and Practice"*](http://books.google.com/books?id=qDPMLisVSCIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Weintraub,%20Jordan%20canonical%20form,%20Theory%20and%20practice&hl=en&ei=L8raTeK6LYPFswau_Mj3Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). Besides [the notes by **Matthews**](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/) are very appropriate for a second course on linear and matrix algebra, developing, proving and explaining a great deal about canonical forms.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try [*Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra*](http://www.matrixanalysis.com/) by Meyer and *Linear Algebra and its Applications* by Strang.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.